# table Ord has no column named _id

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i have created a table named **Ord** in SQlite and the schema is :

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE Ord (
int _id,
text Name
);
```

I use a function named **insert_by_id** and the code :

```
  public void insert_by_id(int id){                             
   ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
   contentValues.put(KEY_ID, id);
db.insert(TABLE_NAME2, null, contentValues);
}
```

ofcourse : private static final String **TABLE_NAME2** = "Ord";
and :   public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";

but when i'm trying to use it with the onClick event i get the error :

#### *01-11 02:13:38.622: E/Database(424): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Ord has no column named _id: , while compiling: INSERT INTO Ord(_id) VALUES(?);*

The part where i want to insert by id data is this :

```
            plus[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {

                     Salad_Num[k]++;
                     mySQLiteAdapter.insert_by_id(Salad_Num[k]);            
                     quant.setText(""+Salad_Num[k]);
                 }
             });
```

I guess there is no typo and as long as i have searched for similar answers here all of them are creating the database inside the code and not before trying to run the project.

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment as I'm not sure if it matters or not, but I'm throwing it out there. Set _id as the primary field in the database create. `CREATE TABLE Ord (
int _id primary,
text Name
);`.

Comment: Did you try complete uninstall of your app and redoply?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking next, maybe the table on the emulator is an old version with no _id for some reason. Pull the sqlite file from the emulator and open in SQLitebrowser to double-check the table.

Comment: no, but i created a new table Ord2 and used it in the project and got the same error.

Comment: bad SQlite syntax...first the field second the type...
CREATE TABLE Ord ( _id int, Name text);

appreciate both ur help

Comment: Lol, can't believe I missed that :-)

Comment: yeah...cant believe it was so simple...i had no previous experience with SQLite...if u want add the correct answer so i can mark the Question as answered. thank u both :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL syntax error! you are trying to create a column "text" with data type "Name". Check the correct syntax below, you have already fixed it i guess.

```
CREATE TABLE Ord (
int _id,
Name text
);
```